# Need to format string output to certain length, how do I count each char in a string to a set limit

Tags: java, string

I need to limit the length of the output string without formatting the input string itself. I want to count each char of the string that is read up to an arbitrary limit - let's say 20 - at which point it will start printing on a new line. However, I also need words to stay whole with no hyphens or anything, so I figured once I get to the point of counting each char I can introduce a logic statement so that it won't start a new line until it reaches a space after the 20 limit.

Is this possible?

After the help from The Badge below, this is where I am at the moment:

Code:

```
    responder.printWelcome();

    while(!finished) {
        HashSet<String> input = reader.getInput();

        if(input.contains("bye")) {
            finished = true;
        }
        else {
            String response = responder.generateResponse(input);
            Scanner scan = new Scanner (response);
            int count = 0;
            scan.useDelimiter("");
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            while (scan.hasNext()){
                if (count <20){
                    sb.append(scan.next());
                    count = count + 1;

                }
                else{
                    System.out.println(sb);
                    sb.delete(0, 20);
                    count = 0;
                }

            }
        }
    }
    responder.printGoodbye();
}
```

EDIT: Fixed the output issue with it not printing the whole sentence (although it's still not printing out the end of the sentence - 'configuration.' only comes out as 'configurati')

Can anyone help me format it so that it won't print a new line until it reaches a space?

EDIT2: Thanks to Anuswadh, I'm getting ever closer I feel! Although the new issue is that it seems to be dropping characters.

when I input this text:

> I was born on the 30th November 1874 into the family of the Dukes of Marlborough, a branch of the Spencer family - you may know of my distant relative, Diana Spencer.

It returns this text:

> I was born on the 30h November 1874 into te family of the Dukes f Marlborough, a brach of the Spencer famil - you may know of my distant relative, Dina.

Comment: And what have you tried ?

Comment: share what you have done so far

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. [You'll need to show us what you have tried, and where you are exactly stuck](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182266/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users/182380#182380).

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a Scanner object passing it a String.

```
Scanner scan = new Scanner (string_name);
```

then build a loop that read characters with your conditions
for example

```
int count = 0;
scan.useDelimiter("");
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
while (scan.hasNext()){
  if (count <20){
   sb.append(scan.next());
}else{
  //do what ever you want 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can see if the next character is a white space and iterate until you reach it if it is not so.

```
responder.printWelcome();

while(!finished) {
    HashSet<String> input = reader.getInput();

    if(input.contains("bye")) {
        finished = true;
    }
    else {
        String response = responder.generateResponse(input);
        Scanner scan = new Scanner (response);
        int count = 0;
        scan.useDelimiter("");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        while (scan.hasNext()){
            if (count <20){
                sb.append(scan.next());
                count = count + 1;

            }
            else{
                 String c = scan.next();
                    if (!(c.equals(" "))) {
                        if (sb.charAt(sb.length() - 1) != ' ') {
                            while (!(c.equals(" "))) {
                                if (!scan.hasNext()) {
                                    break;
                                }
                                c = scan.next();
                                sb.append(c);
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println(sb);
                        sb = new StringBuilder();
                        count = 0;
            }

        }
    }
}
responder.printGoodbye();
```

}

Comment: Thank you for this! Although there still appears to be a formatting error, probably on my part - when I input this text:

>I was born on the 30th November 1874 into the family of the Dukes of Marlborough, a branch of the Spencer family - you may know of my distant relative, Diana Spencer

It returns this text:

>I was born on the 30h 
November 1874 into te 
family of the Dukes 
f Marlborough, a brach 
of the Spencer famil 
- you may know of my
distant relative, Dina